# using angular-ui-routers ui-sref going to a sub state of a parameterized state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ui-sref

Unclear question, i know but let me explain. I have the following structure:

```
.state('item', {
  url:'item/{id:[0-9]+}',
//etc
})
.state('item.general', {
  url: '/general'
})
```

Where item is a state to which you provide an id to see the specific item, and then general is a tab under that item.
Now I want to use ui-sref to go to the general state of an item with a specific id. If I just wanted to go to the item I'd do this:

```
<a ui-sref="item({id:1})">link</a>
```

but I don't want to go to item, but the general state. I've tried just doing somtheing like this

```
<a ui-sref="item.general({id:1})">link</a>
```

but this did not work.

Is there a way to achieve what I am trying? using ui-sref going to a sub state where the parent has an Id parameter.

Comment: Which version of angular are you using? Can you create a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/) please? I've just double checked and `<a ui-sref="item.general({id:1})">link</a>` takes me to `/item/1/general`.

Comment: Ok. angular: 1.4.8, and ui.router: 0.2.15. Maybe it's something else i'm doing wrong then

Comment: It must be - I checked too - `item.general({id: 1})` should be working ok.

Comment: My bad! realised I forgot to add the module as a dependency containing these states to the main module. It is working fine! Thanks